# armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 SQLCipher Android:

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I am try to implement SQLcipher. It works fine. I have an doubt about this `armeabi, armeabi-v7a,`and`x86`. I am adding these folders inside of `libs` folder which contains `.so` files. But i need to know all these files are required?. Because all the three folders are contains

```
libdatabase_sqlcipher.so
libsqlcipher_android.so
libstlport_shared.so
```

files. Please help me to find out the difference between these. 
I have read some articles. It says all the folders are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SQLCipher for Android does need those native libraries, however the platforms your application will dictate how many of those folders you will need to include.  At a minimum you will need to include the `armeabi` folder.

Comment: Thanks i've already delete armeabi-v7a,andx86 it works fine. I am asking is it produce any problem with different devices or something.

Comment: You would run into problems if your application did not include them and you attempt to deploy your application on an armeabi-v7a, or x86 Android device, otherwise there should not be an issue.

Comment: So it must be need three folders?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but AFAIK "armeabi-v7a" and "x86" devices would fallback to the "armeabi" folder (if it's the only one present) using a compatibility layer (f.ex., Houdini for Intel), with a certain impact. It depends on your specific app requirements. But I would not be surprised if there are devices that don't fallback at all, I've seen cheap made-in-China tablets without the Google Play app, without location support, without a lot of different and scary things...